# How to sort terms with diacritical signs?

Tags: terms, sort

I have list of terms which happens to be the [Polish Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_alphabet).

Here's how I list these terms:

```
<ul>
<?php 
   $terms = get_terms("taxonomy", array('orderby' => 'title', 'hide_empty' => 0));
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      echo "<li><a href='". get_term_link( $term->slug, $term->taxonomy ) ."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>";
   } ?>
```

Everything works like a charm excepting one thing - the letter that is supposed to be after "L" ("Ł") is always the last element o that list (so it's after "Ż", not "L"). Is there any way to fix it? I've been trying multiple WP versions including Polish builds.

Any ideas? I can always do two foreach loops for A-L and M-Ż and add that one between them, but would love to do that with more class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the database collation to `utf8_polish_ci` in your `wp-config.php` to get correct sorting.

Comment: I set `define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_polish_ci');` in wp-config.php but it doesn't seem to help, the letter is still the very last one.

Comment: @stillanonymous123 You _might_ have to run an `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: As far as I understand I have to update my tables (all of them or just wp_terms?) using `ALTER TABLE wp_terms CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset`? `utf8_polish_ci` is not a charset according to mysql manual so which one should I use? Thanks a lot!